# How to debug failing updates for custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, block-editor

**Issue Overview**

I have a post that I am working on for a few days, when I try to update it I get a error updating failed.

**Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)**

Make a post

Select a sub industry taxonomy

Save (I get the error).

**Expected Behavior**

It should update the post

**Current Behavior**

I get a error message "Updating failed"

**Screenshots / Video**

https://i.gyazo.com/66f11f5992c6780a62906ac6e4eb20d0.png

**What I have done so far**

Disabled Plugins one by one
Disabled All Plugins just leaving ACF and CPT UI
All points to some Gutenberg issue

**Debug Info from Custom Post Tools**

```
### Begin Custom Post Type UI Debug Info ###

Multisite:                No

SITE_URL:                 https://ktccidtdsdev.wpengine.com
HOME_URL:                 https://ktccidtdsdev.wpengine.com

WordPress Version:        5.5.1
Permalink Structure:      /%postname%/
Active Theme:             UnderStrap BUILDER 

Registered Post Types:    post, page, attachment, revision, nav_menu_item, custom_css, customize_changeset, oembed_cache, user_request, wp_block, acf-field-group, acf-field, wpcf7_contact_form, benchmark_post, company, company_post, investor_post, notable_example, ignore, vc_grid_item, aoc_popup, vc4_templates

PHP Version:              7.3.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
MySQL Version:            5.7.29
Web Server Info:          Apache

Show On Front:            page
Page On Front:            Home 2 (#3405)
Page For Posts:           Basic Blog (#2823)

WordPress Memory Limit:   40MB

TOTAL PLUGINS: 36

MU PLUGINS: (4)

Force Strong Passwords - WPE Edition: 1.6.4
WP Engine Seamless Login Plugin: 1.5.5
WP Engine Security Auditor: 1.0.9
WP Engine System: 4.0.0

ACTIVE PLUGINS: (34)

AddToAny Share Buttons: 1.7.42
Admin Columns: 4.2.2
Advanced Custom Fields: 5.9.1
Advanced Custom Fields PRO: 5.8.12
All-in-One WP Migration: 7.28
Better Search Replace: 1.3.3
Contact Form 7: 5.2.2
CSS Animator for VC: 1.6
Custom plugin for KnowTheChain by TBL: 0.1.1
Custom Post Type UI: 1.8.1
Disable REST API: 1.5
Display Posts: 3.0.2
Duplicate / Clone Pages and Posts: 1.2
Easy Forms for Mailchimp: 6.7.0
Fonts Plugin | Google Fonts Typography: 2.3.1
GDPR Compliance for Mailchimp: 1.3.3
Google Analytics Dashboard for WP (GADWP): 6.2.2
Hide admin menu: 1.0.9
Jetpack by WordPress.com: 9.0.2
LayerSlider WP: 5.5.1
Mailgun: 1.7.1
Popup anything on click: 1.7.7
Redirection: 4.8
Sassy Social Share: 3.3.13
SSL Insecure Content Fixer: 2.7.2
Ultimate Addons for WPBakery Page Builder: 3.19.3
What The File: 1.5.4
WordPress Importer: 0.7
WPBakery Page Builder: 6.1
WP Clone by WP Academy: 2.2.10
WP Mail SMTP: 2.4.0
WP Migrate DB Pro: 1.8.5
WP MVC: 1.3.20
WP Post Popup: 3.6.2

INACTIVE PLUGINS: (2)

Classic Editor: 1.6
Redux: 4.1.21

Post Types: 
{"benchmark_post":{"name":"benchmark_post","label":"Benchmark Posts","singular_label":"benchmark_post","description":"","public":"false","publicly_queryable":"false","show_ui":"false","show_in_nav_menus":"false","delete_with_user":"false","show_in_rest":"false","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","has_archive":"false","has_archive_string":"","exclude_from_search":"false","capability_type":"post","hierarchical":"false","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","menu_position":"","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_menu_string":"","menu_icon":"","supports":["title","editor","thumbnail"],"taxonomies":[],"labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","add_new":"","add_new_item":"","edit_item":"","new_item":"","view_item":"","view_items":"","search_items":"","not_found":"","not_found_in_trash":"","parent_item_colon":"","featured_image":"","set_featured_image":"","remove_featured_image":"","use_featured_image":"","archives":"","insert_into_item":"","uploaded_to_this_item":"","filter_items_list":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":"","attributes":"","name_admin_bar":"","item_published":"","item_published_privately":"","item_reverted_to_draft":"","item_scheduled":"","item_updated":""},"custom_supports":""},"company":{"name":"company","label":"Companies","singular_label":"Company","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","delete_with_user":"false","show_in_rest":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","has_archive":"false","has_archive_string":"","exclude_from_search":"false","capability_type":"post","hierarchical":"false","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","menu_position":"","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_menu_string":"","menu_icon":"","supports":["title","editor","excerpt"],"taxonomies":[],"labels":{"menu_name":"Companies","all_items":"All Companies","add_new":"","add_new_item":"","edit_item":"","new_item":"","view_item":"","view_items":"","search_items":"","not_found":"","not_found_in_trash":"","parent_item_colon":"","featured_image":"","set_featured_image":"","remove_featured_image":"","use_featured_image":"","archives":"","insert_into_item":"","uploaded_to_this_item":"","filter_items_list":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":"","attributes":"","name_admin_bar":"","item_published":"","item_published_privately":"","item_reverted_to_draft":"","item_scheduled":"","item_updated":""},"custom_supports":""},"company_post":{"name":"company_post","label":"Company Posts","singular_label":"Company Post","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","delete_with_user":"false","show_in_rest":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","has_archive":"false","has_archive_string":"","exclude_from_search":"false","capability_type":"post","hierarchical":"false","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","menu_position":"","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_menu_string":"","menu_icon":"","supports":["title","editor","thumbnail","excerpt"],"taxonomies":[],"labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","add_new":"","add_new_item":"","edit_item":"","new_item":"","view_item":"","view_items":"","search_items":"","not_found":"","not_found_in_trash":"","parent_item_colon":"","featured_image":"","set_featured_image":"","remove_featured_image":"","use_featured_image":"","archives":"","insert_into_item":"","uploaded_to_this_item":"","filter_items_list":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":"","attributes":"","name_admin_bar":"","item_published":"","item_published_privately":"","item_reverted_to_draft":"","item_scheduled":"","item_updated":""},"custom_supports":""},"investor_post":{"name":"investor_post","label":"Investor Posts","singular_label":"Investor Post","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","delete_with_user":"false","show_in_rest":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","has_archive":"false","has_archive_string":"","exclude_from_search":"false","capability_type":"post","hierarchical":"false","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","menu_position":"","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_menu_string":"","menu_icon":"","supports":["title","editor","thumbnail","excerpt"],"taxonomies":["company_sector","company_post_topic"],"labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","add_new":"","add_new_item":"","edit_item":"","new_item":"","view_item":"","view_items":"","search_items":"","not_found":"","not_found_in_trash":"","parent_item_colon":"","featured_image":"","set_featured_image":"","remove_featured_image":"","use_featured_image":"","archives":"","insert_into_item":"","uploaded_to_this_item":"","filter_items_list":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":"","attributes":"","name_admin_bar":"","item_published":"","item_published_privately":"","item_reverted_to_draft":"","item_scheduled":"","item_updated":""},"custom_supports":""},"notable_example":{"name":"notable_example","label":"Notable Examples","singular_label":"Notable Example","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","delete_with_user":"false","show_in_rest":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","has_archive":"false","has_archive_string":"","exclude_from_search":"false","capability_type":"post","hierarchical":"false","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","menu_position":"","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_menu_string":"","menu_icon":"","supports":["title","editor","thumbnail"],"taxonomies":[],"labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","add_new":"","add_new_item":"","edit_item":"","new_item":"","view_item":"","view_items":"","search_items":"","not_found":"","not_found_in_trash":"","parent_item_colon":"","featured_image":"","set_featured_image":"","remove_featured_image":"","use_featured_image":"","archives":"","insert_into_item":"","uploaded_to_this_item":"","filter_items_list":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":"","attributes":"","name_admin_bar":"","item_published":"","item_published_privately":"","item_reverted_to_draft":"","item_scheduled":"","item_updated":""},"custom_supports":""},"ignore":{"name":"ignore","label":"ignore","singular_label":"ignore","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","delete_with_user":"false","show_in_rest":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","has_archive":"false","has_archive_string":"","exclude_from_search":"false","capability_type":"post","hierarchical":"false","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","menu_position":"","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_menu_string":"","menu_icon":"","supports":["title","editor","thumbnail"],"taxonomies":[],"labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","add_new":"","add_new_item":"","edit_item":"","new_item":"","view_item":"","view_items":"","search_items":"","not_found":"","not_found_in_trash":"","parent_item_colon":"","featured_image":"","set_featured_image":"","remove_featured_image":"","use_featured_image":"","archives":"","insert_into_item":"","uploaded_to_this_item":"","filter_items_list":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":"","attributes":"","name_admin_bar":"","item_published":"","item_published_privately":"","item_reverted_to_draft":"","item_scheduled":"","item_updated":""},"custom_supports":""}}


Taxonomies: 
{"company_category":{"name":"company_category","label":"Company Categories","singular_label":"Company Category","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","hierarchical":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"1","rewrite_hierarchical":"0","show_admin_column":"false","show_in_rest":"true","show_in_quick_edit":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","edit_item":"","view_item":"","update_item":"","add_new_item":"","new_item_name":"","parent_item":"","parent_item_colon":"","search_items":"","popular_items":"","separate_items_with_commas":"","add_or_remove_items":"","choose_from_most_used":"","not_found":"","no_terms":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":""},"meta_box_cb":"","object_types":["company","company_post","investor_post"]},"company_year_category":{"name":"company_year_category","label":"Sectors","singular_label":"Sector","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","hierarchical":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"1","rewrite_hierarchical":"0","show_admin_column":"false","show_in_rest":"true","show_in_quick_edit":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","edit_item":"","view_item":"","update_item":"","add_new_item":"","new_item_name":"","parent_item":"","parent_item_colon":"","search_items":"","popular_items":"","separate_items_with_commas":"","add_or_remove_items":"","choose_from_most_used":"","not_found":"","no_terms":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":""},"meta_box_cb":"","object_types":["company"]},"topic":{"name":"topic","label":"Topics","singular_label":"Topic","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","hierarchical":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"1","rewrite_hierarchical":"0","show_admin_column":"false","show_in_rest":"true","show_in_quick_edit":"","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","edit_item":"","view_item":"","update_item":"","add_new_item":"","new_item_name":"","parent_item":"","parent_item_colon":"","search_items":"","popular_items":"","separate_items_with_commas":"","add_or_remove_items":"","choose_from_most_used":"","not_found":"","no_terms":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":""},"meta_box_cb":"","object_types":["company_post","investor_post"]},"company_brand":{"name":"company_brand","label":"Brands","singular_label":"Company Brand","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","hierarchical":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"1","rewrite_hierarchical":"0","show_admin_column":"false","show_in_rest":"true","show_in_quick_edit":"true","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","edit_item":"","view_item":"","update_item":"","add_new_item":"","new_item_name":"","parent_item":"","parent_item_colon":"","search_items":"","popular_items":"","separate_items_with_commas":"","add_or_remove_items":"","choose_from_most_used":"","not_found":"","no_terms":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":""},"meta_box_cb":"","object_types":["company"]},"subindustry":{"name":"subindustry","label":"Sub Industries","singular_label":"Subindustry","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","hierarchical":"true","show_ui":"true","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"1","rewrite_hierarchical":"0","show_admin_column":"false","show_in_rest":"true","show_in_quick_edit":"","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","edit_item":"","view_item":"","update_item":"","add_new_item":"","new_item_name":"","parent_item":"","parent_item_colon":"","search_items":"","popular_items":"","separate_items_with_commas":"","add_or_remove_items":"","choose_from_most_used":"","not_found":"","no_terms":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":""},"meta_box_cb":"","object_types":["company"]},"company_year":{"name":"company_year","label":"Company Years","singular_label":"Company Year","description":"","public":"true","publicly_queryable":"true","hierarchical":"false","show_ui":"true","show_in_menu":"true","show_in_nav_menus":"true","query_var":"true","query_var_slug":"","rewrite":"true","rewrite_slug":"","rewrite_withfront":"1","rewrite_hierarchical":"0","show_admin_column":"false","show_in_rest":"true","show_in_quick_edit":"","rest_base":"","rest_controller_class":"","labels":{"menu_name":"","all_items":"","edit_item":"","view_item":"","update_item":"","add_new_item":"","new_item_name":"","parent_item":"","parent_item_colon":"","search_items":"","popular_items":"","separate_items_with_commas":"","add_or_remove_items":"","choose_from_most_used":"","not_found":"","no_terms":"","items_list_navigation":"","items_list":""},"meta_box_cb":"","default_term":"","object_types":["company"]}}


### End Debug Info ###
```

Comment: This question is too broad to be fully answered. There are a lot of 3rd party plugins and themes in play here that would need to be debugged one at time. Then the settings of the plugins may come into play. I would suggest taking a full backup of your website, install the WordPress Health Check and Troubleshooting plugin, and ensure it's not a conflict with a specific plugin or even your theme. Then you can open a support topic with the authors of that plugin or theme.

Comment: I disabled All the plugins except Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Types UI and same behavior

Comment: I also deactivated the REST API via functions.php, and installed the classic editor, and it was working, all points to be a Gutenberg issue